# Passing (local variable)List<Courses> and showing the list at the view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send a local variable which is a list and showing it at the View.
I've been trying all sorts of ways but nothing seems to be working and I'm kind of desperate.

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Project.Models;
using System.Configuration;
using Project.Dal;
using Project.ViewModel;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult StudentCourse()
        {
            var id = (int)Session["ID"];

            StudentInCourseDal SICD = new StudentInCourseDal();
            CoursesDal CD = new CoursesDal();
            List<Courses> courseinfo = new List<Courses>();
            //var course = (from x in SICD.StudentInCourses where x.studentID.Equals(id) select x.CourseID).ToList();
            //var courses = (from x in CD.Courses where x.CourseID.Equals(course) select x.Coursesinfo).ToList();
            /* get all courses ids */
            var courses =
                (from x in SICD.StudentInCourses
                 where x.studentID.Equals(id)
                 select x.CourseID).ToList();

            /* get each course info thats in courses */
            var coursesInfo =
                (from x in CD.Courses
                 where courses.Contains(x.CourseID)
                 select x).ToList();
            return View("StudentCourse", coursesInfo);
        }
        public ActionResult StudentExams()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

}
```

**DAL**

```
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Dal
{
    public class CoursesDal : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Courses>().ToTable("Courses");
        }
        public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Courses
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int LectureID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Day { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public TimeSpan Hour { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime? moedADate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime? moedBDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string moedAClass { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string moedBClass { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**CourseViewModel**

```
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    public class CoursesViewModel
    {
        public Courses courseName { get; set; }
        public List<Courses> coursesName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentCourseView**

```
@model Project.Models.Courses
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
    .table1 {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .cell {
        border: solid 1px #999;
    }

    .cell-1 {
        border: solid 1px #999;
        background: #999;
        color: #FFF;
    }
</style>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>StudentCourse</title>
    <link href="~/styles/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="~/styles/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/Account/StudentHomePage" class="Button">Home</a>
            <a href="/Student/StudentSchedule" class="Button">Schedule</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    More
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/Student/StudentExams" class="Button">Exams</a>
                    <a href="/Student/StudentCourse" class="Button">Course</a>
                    <a href="/Student/StudentChat" class="Button">Chat</a>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <center>
            <center>
                <h1 style="color:white">Courses details</h1>
                <table id="customers">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course ID</th>
                        <th>Course Hour</th>
                        <th>Course Day</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                         <b>
                            <b>Course ID : @Model.CourseID</b>
                            <b>Course ID : @Model.Day</b>
                            <b>Course ID : @Model.Hour</b>
                         </b>  
                        }

                        <tr>

                    </table>
                </center>
            </center>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is like this:

In my DB theres 3 tables, one for students (there I get ID and full name of the students)
Compare it to the table StudentInCourse (There I got ID of student and ID of course)
and show all the courses that has the same ID in the Course table.

for example:

I have student entering with ID of 2.
I need to check if this ID has any courses ID in the DB table of StudentInCourse.(example student got ID 2 and he links to courseID 3)
If it does, go to course table and take all the courses who has ID of 3 and show all their info.

Comment: you are passing a list object to your view but your view is expecting a course class object. Also, there are many concerns in your code. Is it compiling fine for you?

Comment: It actually does. You have any idea how can I tell view to expect the list to enter?

Comment: Change `@model Project.Models.Courses` to `@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Courses>`

Comment: Add an answer please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `courseinfo` which is `List<Courses>` but you your view is expecting the a model of type `Project.Models.Courses`.

If you still want to pass list of Courses then change the model in the view as below.

```
    @model List<Project.Models.Courses>
```

Also, when you want to access the properties of Model then you need iterate the list using foreach as below.

```
@foreach(var course in Model)
{
 <b>
                        <b>Course ID : @course.CourseID</b>
                        <b>Course ID : @course.Day</b>
                        <b>Course ID : @course.Hour</b>
                     </b> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Rejesh G, It works and now show all the table's I was needed! 
Appreciate it a lot! :D